# can i transfer from Haneda to Narita in 3:30 hour

Tags: transit, japan

I booked a flight from Australia to Netherlands via Japan.
I have to transit from Haneda to Narita in 3:30 hour. Is that possible?

Comment: Is that on a single ticket? If it isn’t you can probably just forget about it. Also have you checked if you are even allowed to enter Japan under current Covid restrictions?

Comment: Timatic seems to say you need a visa to be able to travel from one to the other, and I believe they don’t currently issue such visas, so even on a single ticket, probably not unless you are a Japanese citizen.

Comment: I strongly recommend against that. While it's not impossible, it would be very high risk. Even if it's a single ticket, most airlines state that airport to airport transfers are your responsibility and you would be a no-show if you miss the connection (if the flights are on time).

Comment: At this point in time this transit is basically not allowed due to Covid restrictions. Transiting Japan is allowed for some passengers, but only with the same airport.

Comment: You can contact the Japanese embassy in Australia for details to see if they would grant a transit visa in your case, but this is probably going to take some time. Also the ANA minimum connection time for International to International between HND and NRT is precisely 3:30, so you are right at the limit if you are on a single ticket. On separate tickets just forget about it, the chances of making it are extremely low IMHO and you would be on the hook to buy and pay for a new ticket, hotels, meals, etc.